# CodeSign Error: Code signing is required for product type "Application"

Tags: ios, ssh, jailbreak, unsigned, ipa

Hey I'm trying to install a unsigned IPA on my jailbroken iPhone running iOS 8.1 but when I go to build it for my device (as done in this guide: http://www.sysrage.net/guides/ios-programming/building-and-running-ios-applications-without-a-paid-developer-license) I get the above error. I've set all the code signing things to not code sign but when I go to build I always get this error. I've done this in the past before (with the same guide) and I'm using the same project settings as I have in the past but nothing seems to work. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One way of installing your app on your jailbroken device is to use appcake from cydia.iphonecake.com repo. First have your app.ipa file handy. Second install appcake from cydia.iphonecake.com repo. Then Simply add Yourapp.ipa to var/mobile/Media/AppCake/Imported via ssh. Then navigate to the appcake application and go to the "Downloads" tab and then "Imported" tab on the top. You should see your application there. Press on it then press install. If you need more detailed instructions on how to ssh or extract the .ipa file from xcode let me know.